# input() e raw_input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Segundo a documentação do Python 2.x, recomenda-se o uso da função `raw_input` ao invés da `input`. De forma contrária, na documentação do Python 3.x, a função `raw_input` nem mesmo aparece. Então será que a função `input` no Python 3.x substitui a função `raw_input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Python 2 existem as funções `input` e `raw_input`, mas a primeira raramente é usada porque ela só aceita literais sintaticamente válidos, ou seja, números, ou strings entre aspas, etc. A função `raw_input` é muito mais útil: ela aceita qualquer *string*, e fica sendo sua responsabilidade lidar com ela.

No Python 3 a função `raw_input` passou a se chamar `input`, e a velha função `input` praticamente inútil foi removida.

No Python 3 aconteceram várias "limpezas" deste tipo.

Comment: Eu não diria que eles tiraram o input por ser uma função inútil. O problema maior é que o `eval` do `input` no Python 2.x permite que o usuário execute código Python arbitrário. Isso pode ser muito perigoso.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, o `input` do Python 3.x é o `raw_input` do Python 2.x. Essa mudança pode ser encontrada no [changelog da versão 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins):

> PEP 3111: `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`. That is, the new `input()` function reads a line from `sys.stdin` and returns it with the trailing newline stripped. It raises `EOFError` if the input is terminated prematurely. To get the old behavior of `input()`, use `eval(input())`.

Para mais detalhes, veja a [PEP 3111](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/).