# Criando um programa de chat. Como fazer que dois conversem simultaneamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
# nao tem servidor UDP no google -> vamos usar netcat como servidor UDP!
#Programa de chat: so fala um de cada vez
#implementar falando ao mesmo tempo

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

"""
pacotes_recebidos = client.recvfrom(1024) devolve uma tupla:
(' llallalaaaa\n', ('192.168.1.4', 667))

msg recebida + (IP,porta)
"""
try:    
    while 6: #while True
        #client.sendto(input("Voce: ") + "\n", ("192.168.1.4", 668))
        #client.sendto (bytes(input("Voce: ")).encode('utf8') + bytes("\n").encode('utf8'), bytes(("192.168.1.4", 668)).encode('utf8'))
        client.sendto((input("Voce: ")).encode('utf8') + ("\n").encode('‌​utf‌​8'),("192.168.1.7", 661))
        # endereço do servidor UDP do kali linux usando netcat
        msg, friend = client.recvfrom(1024)
        print(str(friend) + ": " + str(msg))
 #se quiser apenas o ip: use friend[0]

    client.close()

except Exception as erro:
    print("Conexao falhou ")
    print("O erro foi: ", erro)
    client.close()
```

O programa acima em Python *2.7* funcionou ao trocar `input` por `raw_input` e não sei o porquê.

Ao rodar em Python *3.5* (com `input` ao invés de `raw_input`) eu tentei enviar uma mensagem "oi" e o seguinte erro ocorreu:

> ('O erro foi: ', NameError("name 'oi' is not defined",))

Gostaria de fazer com que 2 pessoas pudessem conversar simultaneamente, como fazer? No momento, apenas uma pessoa de cada vez consegue digitar a mensagem.

Temos que aguardar um dos participantes escrever e teclar <kbd>Enter</kbd> para continuar.

Este é o cliente. Estou usando como servidor o `netcat`.
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: tem um bom toturial http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_tcp_server_client_chat_server_chat_client_select.php

Comment: @miguel, obrigado

Comment: Consegue me dizer o que ocorre com input() x raw_input() ?

Comment: `raw_input()` não existe em python3, fica só `input()`, talvez seja isso

Comment: Ao rodar em python 2 com raw_input() funciona. Em python 3 eu troco para input() e aparece o erro que descrevi!

Comment: Não sei, corri esse codigo aqui e não deu esse erro

Comment: Mas em python 3.5? Eu estou usando pycharm e python 3.5 em BackBox Linux.

Comment: ha... Eu uso python 3.4

Comment: @Miguel, eu li o tutorial mas não consegui resolver. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Veja: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkfwX6RjRaI . Já o fiz a uns anos e lembro-me que é bom.. Python2 mas deve dar para converter em 3

Comment: @Miguel, vc disse que executou o script em python 3.4 e não deu o erro. Como você executou? No pycharm dá erro!

Comment: Deu mas não foi o mesmo que lhe deu a si. Experimenta na linha isto: `input("Voce: ") + "\n".encode('UTF-8')...`

Comment: client.sendto( input("Voce: ") +"\n".encode('UTF-8')‌, ("192.168.1.4", 668))  : SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: Eu tentei:         client.sendto (bytes(input("Voce: "),'ut‌​f-8') + bytes("\n",'ut‌​f-8'), bytes(("192.168.1.4", 668),'utf-8'))    . O erro foi:  unknown encoding: ut‌​f-8

Comment: Se eu tiro o 'utf-8' : client.sendto (bytes(input("Voce: ")) + bytes("\n"), bytes(("192.168.1.4", 668))) ->O erro foi:  string argument without an encoding

Comment: Resolvi o erro: só falta a conversa simultanea:         client.sendto((input("Voce: ")).encode('utf8') + ("\n").encode('‌​utf‌​8'),("192.168.1.7", 661))
        print(str(friend) + ": " + str(msg))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O programa acima em Python *2.7* funcionou ao trocar `input` por `raw_input` e não sei o porquê.

No Python *2.x* o método [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) é usado para interpretar e avaliar [expressões](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expressions), veja um exemplo:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input()
5 + 9
14
>>> x = input()
"stack"
>>> y = input()
"overflow"
>>> x + y
'stackoverflow'
>>>
```

O erro informado, [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError), indica que você está executando o *script* no Python *2.x*.

Para mais informações veja a pergunta: [**`input()` e `raw_input()`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145962/6454)

> No momento, apenas uma pessoa de cada vez consegue digitar a mensagem, temos que aguardar um dos participantes escrever e teclar para continuar.

Isso acontece porque por padrão um *socket* é bloqueante, configurado para enviar e receber informações, pausando a execução do *script* até que uma determinada ação seja concluída.

Por exemplo, as chamadas ao método [`send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) irão esperar por espaço disponível no *buffer* para fazer o envio dos dados, as chamadas ao método [`recv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) por sua vez, irão esperar até que a outra parte da comunicação envie os dados a seres lidos.

O controle não é devolvido ao programa até que tenha espaço no *buffer* para o envio, ou que seja recebido algum *byte* da outra parte da comunicação, ou algum erro ocorra.

No Python para usar o *socket* como não-bloqueante, usa-se o método [`socket.setblocking`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) com o argumento `False`, ou o método [`socket.settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) com o valor *0*.

```
import socket

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
cliente.setblocking(False)
```

Vai ser usado o módulo [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#module-select), para monitorar a entrada de dados do usuário no terminal.

> This module provides access to the `select()` and `poll()` functions
>   available in most operating systems, `devpoll()` available on Solaris
>   and derivatives, `epoll()` available on Linux 2.5+ and `kqueue()`
>   available on most BSD. **Note that on Windows**, it only works for
>   *sockets*; on other operating systems, it also works for other file
>   types (in particular, on Unix, it works on *pipes*). It cannot be used
>   on regular files to determine whether a file has grown since it was
>   last read.

**Nota**: Se estiver usando Windows, o `select` pode não ter o comportamento esperado como pode ser visto destacado no texto acima.

Código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket, sys, select

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
cliente.setblocking(False)

serverAddr = ("192.168.1.4", 667)

def mensagem():
    # Verifica se foi digitado algo
    if select.select([sys.stdin,],[],[],0.0)[0]:
        # Formata a string para mandar "Cliente: <entrada>"
        entrada = "Cliente: {}".format(sys.stdin.readline())
        entrada = entrada.encode('utf-8')

        return entrada
    return False

try:
    while 1:
        try:
            msg, friend = cliente.recvfrom(1024)
            # friend[0] - IP / friend[1] - porta

            # rstrip() é para eliminar a quebra de linha
            msg = msg.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
            print("{}: {}".format(friend[0], msg))
        except:
            pass

        try:
            entrada = mensagem()
            if(entrada != False):
                cliente.sendto(entrada, serverAddr)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit("\nChat encerrado!")

    cliente.close()

except Exception as erro:
    print("O erro foi: {}".format(erro))
    client.close()
```